# How to return value from a callback within a function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, return

I'm trying to make a simple function to take a JavaScript `FileEntry` and "convert" it into a JavaScript `File` object. I have the basic function here:

```
function fileEntrytoFile(e){
  var f = 0;

  e.file(function(file){
    f = file;
  });
  return f;
}
```

`f` is still 0 when it is returned. How can I return the `File` object that is being generated by the callback function within?

Comment: You can't, assuming `e.file` is asynchronous. Instead, you could return a promise which will resolve to the file.

Comment: Are you using any promise library like q ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to return a promise, since `FileEntry.file` is asynchronous:

```
function fileEntrytoFile(e){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => e.file(resolve, reject));
}

fileEntrytoFile(fileEntry) . then(file => console.log(file.name));
```

The above uses ES6 arrow functions and ES6 promises.

Comment: This is perfect. I'm watching videos to learn about arrow functions and Promises now! Thank you!